# Manipulating variables in R

Tags: r, append

I am working with a data set that has the following format in R:

```
id  age gender  time1   time2   time3   time4
12  22  0   2   3   2   3
13  35  0   3   4   3   4
14  45  0   4   1   4   1
15  23  0   1   3   5   3
16  67  0   2   2   1   4
17  55  0   4   4   3   2
18  68  1   5   5   4   1
19  90  1   1   6   5   2
20  20  1   3   7   1   2
21  34  1   5   5   3   2
```

I'd like to modify this data set in R in the following manner:

```
time    result  id  age gender
time1   2   12  22  0
time1   3   13  35  0
time1   4   14  45  0
time1   1   15  23  0
time1   2   16  67  0
time1   4   17  55  0 
time1   5   18  68  1
time1   1   19  90  1
time1   3   20  20  1
time1   5   21  34  1
time2   3   12  22  0
time2   4   13  35  0
time2   1   14  45  0
time2   3   15  23  0
time2   2   16  67  0
time2   4   17  55  0 
time2   5   18  68  1
time2   6   19  90  1
time2   7   20  20  1
time2   5   21  34  1
time3   2   12  22  0
time3   3   13  35  0
time3   4   14  45  0
time3   5   15  23  0
time3   1   16  67  0
time3   3   17  55  0
time3   4   18  68  1
time3   5   19  90  1
time3   1   20  20  1
time3   3   21  34  1
```

So, essentially what I am doing here is getting the results, appending them into a singular column. The results are still identified by the time point in which they were collected, the age, id, and gender of that individual.

I've tried append, but I haven't had any success.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This operation is performed by the `gather` function of package `tidyr`.  In your case if your data.frame is df1, do

```
gather(df1, time, result, time1, time2, time3, time4)
```

Comment: Cool, +1. I'm not at all familiar with the `tidyr` package, this looks nice. Can you generalise the time 1-4 bit (say if you had 1000 time columns?).

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon, `time1:time4` should work if they are beside each other

Comment: This is one of Hadley Wickham's packages; this means every function like this with non-standard evaluation comes with a standard evaluation counterpart (`gather_` in this case).  If you want to pass computed arguments using the standard evaluation version is recommended.

Comment: or you can also generalize it like this `gather(df, time, result, c(-id, -age, -gender)) `

Comment: @dimitris_ps or just `gather(df, time, result, -(id:gender))` ;), but I have to admit I can't quite wrap my head around `tidyr` syntax whatsoever

Comment: @David Arenburg the same goes for me for `data.table` :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use `melt` from `reshape2`.

```
melt(df,id.vars=1:3,value.name="result",variable.name="time")

#    id age gender  time result
# 1  12  22      0 time1      2
# 2  13  35      0 time1      3
# 3  14  45      0 time1      4
# 4  15  23      0 time1      1
# 5  16  67      0 time1      2
# 6  17  55      0 time1      4
# 7  18  68      1 time1      5
# 8  19  90      1 time1      1
# 9  20  20      1 time1      3
```